# Is there a way to load large BLOBs without restarting MySQL?

Tags: mysql, percona, blob-storage

I'm trying to move the last few databases off an older mysql server, but one in particular has me stumped:

> ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 595: The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size.

The server being migrated to is running `5.6.29-76.2-log Percona Server`, which appears to have [a workaround](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-20.html#mysqld-5-6-20-innodb) for a transactional consistency bug with large BLOBs.

Since modifying innodb_log_file_size requires a service restart, is there a way to import a database with transactions disabled or something? SQL*Loader has a number of options for disabling transactions on an import, maybe there's a similar tool & setting for MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

There's no workaround, here.  You'll need to restart.

Everything in InnoDB is done in a transaction.  Sometimes it's an implicit one (when autocommit is enabled, each statement executed -- technically -- starts and commits its own transaction) but it's still a transaction in the relevant sense.

The redo log is a critical component, and can only be resized with a restart.